# Reusable assembies classes in the WCF are kept under a different namespace in proxy

Tags: wcf, ambiguity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ambiguous reference in WCF and client application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083994/ambiguous-reference-in-wcf-and-client-application)

I am using few classes from an assembly 'X' in my WCF whereas my client code uses same assembly to refer other set of classes.
This makes it necessary keep reference of assembly 'X' in client application.

which is causing the conflict as the proxy that I get on the client side has keeps the classes from assembly 'X' under different namespace.

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a pre-generated proxy. If you are sharing assemblies between your service and consumer code anyway then just also share the WCF contracts assembly and then use `ChannelFactory` to create a proxy when you need it.

Comment: the code was working well. I updated a method in the service and updated the reference in consumer code which resulted in  such error.

Comment: Like I said. If you're sharing assemblies between service and consumer don't use a proxy. Just directly reference the types you need from the assembly.

Comment: I edited the pre-generated proxy (reference.cs) to resolve the conflict. it works well now.

Comment: Hey @Tom, I avoided use of  pre-generated proxy. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Ashish you already asked this kind of question. When the client needs reference with some classes that are generated by proxy as well then obviously you get ambiguous errors.

There are two ways you can avoid this problem.

1. Reference the service contracts/data contracts assembly directly in the client and instead of creating proxy using svcutil.exe use ChannelFactory as suggested by @hugh.
2. If you are creating the proxy through VS then you configure such that to say the svcutil.exe tool not to recreate the classes that the client already have as I answered you in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083994/ambiguous-reference-in-wcf-and-client-application).

Comment: I posted this question to reword my question in a simple manner. I am working on your approach# 2 to figure out how it helps me. Thanks

Comment: @Mark- I followed the approach# 2. it worked fine for me. But this does not work with the application I am working on. The proxy file generated through svcutil has got few types which conflict with the types in the application (types in the shared assembly). and one more thing I observed is - the Operation contracts are changed e.g.- List<SomeType> Method() is changed to SomeType[] Method() in proxy class.

Comment: "List<SomeType> Method() is changed to SomeType[] Method()" this one you can control same like the re-use types in assembly stuff in the configure service reference dialog.

Comment: I found that configuration in   the dialog. But as I said earlier the actual problem is not   fixed.